# Swift - Shake Motion to do prepareforsegue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue

My intention is to empty values inside 2 arrays - force[] & stiffness[], from another class by prepareforsegue, when user perform a shake gesture. Below is my codes and then the error that i am encountering.

**springViewController1**

```
var springNum : NSInteger = 0

class springViewController1 : UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
var force = [Float]()
var stiffness = [Float] ()
}
```

**springViewController2**

```
class springViewController2 : UITableViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
var forceView2 = [Float]()
var stiffView2 = [Float]()

override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if(event.subtype == UIEventSubtype.MotionShake){

       println("Shaken")
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("reset", sender: self)
    }
}

      override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

      if(segue.identifier == "reset") {

        var svcSpringControl1 = segue.destinationViewController as springViewController1

        springNum = 0

        svcSpringControl1.force.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        svcSpringControl1.stiffness.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

    }
}

}
```

The Code stops here, even though i did not placed any breakpoint inside the code. I click continue programme execution. 
[image: BreakPoint]

The Code stops here.
[image: Error]

Comment: Please continue execution untill you get exception message.

Comment: It crashes here, can't execute anymore. The code does contains any breakpoint in the first place. Not sure why does it stops in between...

Comment: Have you tried adding exception breakpoint?

Comment: I did not add exception breakpoint, but i do put println statements inbetween to test the error. I found out that `var svcSpringControl1 = segue.destinationViewController as springViewController1` causes my code to stop executing.

Comment: Have you tried to log segue.destinationViewController just to be sure it is really springViewController1?

Comment: it does print _<FYP_Table.FEM__Solver_Start: 0x7fb25b72ab90>_ out...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74616/discussion-between-cherry-thia-and-nickcatib).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was to create recursive function to go through view controllers stack:

```
func getSVC1FromVCStack(vc:UIViewController) -> springViewController1{
        if(vc.isKindOfClass(springViewController1)){
            return vc as springViewController1;
        }
        else if(vc.parentViewController == nil){
            return springViewController1.alloc()
        }
        else {
            return getSVC1FromVCStack(vc)
        }

    }
```

And instead of

```
var svcSpringControl1 = segue.destinationViewController as springViewController1
```

It should be

```
var svcSpringControl1 = self.getSVC1FromVCStack(self.parentViewController!) as springViewController1
```

This caused by unwind segue, so the SVC1 was not destination. Another work around could be reference to the SVC1.